# Getting an class element within a class element on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover

I want to hide an element when mouseover.

```
<div class="filmbox">
    <img src="img/cover/django.jpg" onmouseover="cover()" class="filmpic">
    <div class="filmcover">98 pt</div>
    <div class="filmtext">&nbsp;DJANGO</div>
</div>
```

The Filmbox class is multiplied many times so i can't change it to ID.

```
function cover(){
document.getElementsByClassName('filmcover').style.visibility='hidden';
}
```

I could use this instead of getElements..... by I want this div to react on picture not itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Jquery then

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function cover(me){
$(me).next(".filmcover").hide();
}
</script>

<div class="filmbox">
    <img src="img/cover/django.jpg" onmouseover="cover(this)" class="filmpic">
    <div class="filmcover">98 pt</div>
    <div class="filmtext">&nbsp;DJANGO</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that works but it hides ALL filmcover classes on website. How do I point which one exactly I want to hide ?

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done by passing a reference to the image to the `cover()` function using the `this` keyword, as in `onmouseover="cover(this)"`

For example, the following code hides a particilar image on mouse over. It also ensures that only the image that is moused over will be hidden on mouse over (I'm assuming that class `filmpic` applies to multiple images).

```
<script>
function cover(imagetag){
     imagetag.style.visibility="hidden";
}
</script>

<div class="filmbox">
     <img src="img/cover/django.jpg" onmouseover="cover(this)" class="filmpic">
    <div class="filmcover">98 pt</div>
    <div class="filmtext">&nbsp;DJANGO</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".filmpic").hover(
    function(){
        $(".filmcover").hide(); 
    },
    function(){
        $(".filmcover").show();
    }
    );
});
</script>
<div class="filmbox">
<img src="img/cover/django.jpg" class="filmpic">
<div class="filmcover">98 pt</div>
<div class="filmtext">&nbsp;DJANGO</div>
</div>
```